# Bonds in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

I have a quick conceptual question regarding bonds in graph theory. In any graph $G$ is it true that any any maximal star is a bond?

(Definition: A bond is a cut set which does not contain any other cut set.)

Comment: What do you mean by maximal star in this context? The set of edges incident to a single given vertex?

Comment: @Casteels Yes. That is precisely what I mean.

Comment: @Shahab: Why does it have to be a maximal star, i.e., a vertex of maximal degree? What about any other star?

Comment: @Moritz "maximal" in this context probably means "inclusion-maximal", i.e., a star not contained in any other star, so that you're forced to take *all* the edges incident to the given vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Consider a star. Then the edges incident to the center vertex do not form a bond since each of the edges in it are also cuts.

Answer (score 0):

For a vertex $v$ in a graph $G$, let $\delta(v)$ be the set of all edges incident with $v$ (so a maximal star). Then:

> $\delta(v)$ is a bond if and only if $v$ is not a cut-vertex.

*Proof*: Let $C_1,\ldots,C_k$ be the components of the subgraph induced by $V\setminus v$. This induces a partition of $\delta(v)$ into subsets $S_1,\ldots,S_k$ where $S_i$ consists of all edges from $v$ to the vertices in $C_i$. If $v$ is a cut vertex, then $k\geq 2$ and so we see that any $S_i$ is an edge cut strictly contained in $\delta(v)$, so $\delta(v)$ is not a bond.

On the other hand, if $v$ is not a cut vertex then $k=1$ and $S_1=\delta(v)$. For any $T\subsetneq \delta(v)$, the graph $G-T$ is connected. This is because $C_1$ is connected and as there are edges from $v$ to $C_1$ not in $T$ we have that $v$ is connected to $C_1$. Hence $\delta(v)$ is a bond.